# How do I apply two filters on a background image?

Tags: css, background

I'm building a website with a fixed background image. It would be perfect for it to be both grayscale'd and blurred.

Since I discovered on my own that putting `filter: blur(100%)` would blur the whole page and its content, I learned that I could set my filters in a `:before`.

Here is my SCSS:

```
.front-layout {
  font-family: 'Fira-Mono', 'monospace';
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #0e0e0e fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%); <-- I somehow need it here
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width : 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    //filter: grayscale(100%) blur(5%); <-- What I want to achieve
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
 // Some other elements
}
```

FYI, the background image is set dynamically directly in the HTML, that's why it doesn't appear here.

Somehow, I can't get rid of the filter outside the `:before` element, whatever it is, or the filter inside it won't work. To sum up, it's either both or neither of them.

How can I get rid of the first filter and apply two filters in my `:before` element?

**Edit**

I recreated a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sfqd7te/6/) to make some more context, if you run my code, you won't see anything happening unless you uncomment what I commented.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. I can’t tell for sure without a live example to inspect, but right now I would assume that `z-index: -1` hides your pseudo element _behind_ the actual element, and since both have the same background, you have now hidden your blurred and gray-scaled background behind the _un-manipulated_ background of the original element.

Comment: I played around with `z-index`, and while I didn't know why I needed it, it looks like the `:before` attribute goes in front of the div, so if there is anything inside it, such as some text, it will be hidden behind this same div. I updated my question with a JSFiddle for the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::before` pseudo element gets hidden *behind* the element itself (because of the negative z-index), and because that element has the same (un-manipulated) background, the pseudo element gets effectively hidden.

It would work this way, if you could set the background for the pseudo element only, and leave the element’s background transparent - but if you need to use `background: inherit` to get the pseudo element to inherit the parent’s background that was set via inline style, it can’t work this way.

Your only option then is to get your pseudo element positioned between the element’s own background, and its content - so effectively you need to elevate all content “one level up” - in the simplest way that could be done using

```
.front-layout > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sfqd7te/6/

Depending on what the element actually contains, and whether those descendants are themselves positioned in any way, it might work with only that; or you might have to make adjustments (like exclude certain elements from getting relative position applied if they are otherwise positioned already, and/or not overwrite a higher z-index they might already have.)

(`.front-layout > *` limits this to the children of the parent already, descendants further down the tree are no affected.)

Comment: Thank you for making me understanding that, I wouldn't have been able to figure it our alone!